# Displaying an Array of Dictionaries from a Plist to a Tableview, Swift (Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, dictionary, plist

I have been trying for the longest while now to display an Array of dictionaries from a plist into a TableView. This is a snippet of the .plist file.

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>dexNumber</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>formOrder</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>iconFilename</key>
    <string>pokemon-icon-1.png</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Bulbasaur</string>
    <key>yield</key>
    <dict>
        <key>attack</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>defense</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>hp</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>spAttack</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>spDefense</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>speed</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>dexNumber</key>
```

The code never gets to (return self.data.count), as it always returns Unexpected nil while unwrapping optional on this third line.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dex", ofType: "plist"){
        if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
                data = dict.objectForKey("name") as! [String]
            }
    }
```

Changing (let dict = NSDictionary) to (let dict = NSArray) lets me print out the data on the console using println, but it does not let my display any data on the tableview. In addition, that method only allows me to view 1 array with all of its keys, instead of viewing all dictionary objects of one key.

Any instance of trying to view the file as NSDictionary always returns nil. Any instance of returning as NSArray gives a result that can't be displayed on the tableview, but can be displayed on the console using println. This code snippet is an example of code that prints a result.

```
let resultDictionary = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
    println("Loaded dex.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
    var myDict = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
    if let dict = myDict {
        //loading values
        Item0ID = dict.objectAtIndex(0)
        print(Item0ID)
    } else {
        println("WARNING: Couldn't create dictionary from dex.plist! Default values will be used!")
    }
```

This is what returns on the console

> Optional("(\n        {\n        dexNumber = 1;\n        formOrder = 1;\n        iconFilename = \"pokemon-icon-1.png\";\n        name = Bulbasaur;\n        yield =         {\n            attack = 0;\n            defense = 0;\n            hp = 0;\n            spAttack = 1;\n            spDefense = 0;\n            speed = 0;\n        };\n    },\n        {\n        dexNumber = 2;\n

How do I get my view to display a list as text labels and such on the tableview as opposed to nothing at all?

Comment: Name should return String not [String]

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus changing from [String] to String gives the errors "String does not have a member named count" on the return line and "Could not find an overload for subscript" on the cell.textlabel line. Both errors I've run into while trying to display this.

Comment: You should use Swift native dictionary and array

Comment: Your plist is an array of dictionaries not a dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plist contains an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself, so you need to initialize it as an NSArray and then iterate over the elements you want to print and use them to build your data array. Try this:

```
var data = [String]()
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dex", ofType: "plist"){
    if let arrayOfDictionaries = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path){
        for dict in arrayOfDictionaries {
            data.append(dict.objectForKey("name") as! String)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A++ Answer. I had attempted something similar but this 100% got the names to display. Thank you!!